# Implement Consistent Hash Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, redis, consistent-hashing

I am trying to implement a consistent hash based algorithm in java using the following reference for sharding keys to redis -

[Stanford Theory on CH](http://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/s16/l/l1.pdf)

I am trying to understand the best way to generate the hascode for a node and a key. Currently I am using the DigestUtils to generate the hash as follows & 
adding the returned value to the ring/circle -

```
private BigInteger hash(String key) {
    return new BigInteger(DigestUtils.md5Hex(key.getBytes()), 16);
}
```

I wanted to know if this approach sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code [spymemcached client](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client) for Memcache, you can see how that client implemented the Ketama consistent hashing algorithm.  Focus on the following files:

- [KetamaNodeLocator.java](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client/blob/master/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/KetamaNodeLocator.java)
- [KetamaIterator.java](https://github.com/dustin/java-memcached-client/blob/master/src/main/java/net/spy/memcached/KetamaIterator.java)

While not for Redis specifically, the principles are the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Redisson](https://redisson.org) uses `highwayhash` algorithm for sharded Map and Set objects. This algorithm has better distribution characteristic.

Here is a usage example with reference [implementation](https://github.com/google/highwayhash/blob/master/java/com/google/highwayhash/HighwayHash.java):

```
long[] KEY = {0x9e3779b97f4a7c15L, 0xf39cc0605cedc834L, 0x1082276bf3a27251L, 0xf86c6a11d0c18e95L};

byte[] data = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// getting 128 bits hashing
long[] hash128 = HighwayHash.hash128(data, 0, data.length, key);
// getting 256 bits hashing
long[] hash256 = HighwayHash.hash256(data, 0, data.length, key);
```